# Read timed out (java.net.SocketTimeoutException)

Tags: java, server, client, socket-timeout-exception, mule-esb

I have an API developed using Mule ESB which receives the request from the client and forwards the request to another API.
But I found an interesting behaviour in the API that if the client makes an request with a request body that has a new line at the end of the body, then the server waits for timeout and throws **SocketTimeoutException**. I guess the server expects more data from the client and waits for that and finally throws that exception.

Note: I have checked the Content-Length header. The actual Content-Length of the request body is 383 bytes but at the server it shows 380 bytes. So it seems that the server is waiting for those extra 3 bytes. So the question is - why the client is not sending the **new line bytes**?

Anybody has a explanation?

Comment: Is it coded to behave like that? Do you have code to post here?

Comment: @Zaki Anwar Hamdani, I have used a httpconnector build in Mule ESB.